# Angular controller not being instantiated

Tags: angularjs

In the following piece of code, I create a simple controller that does not get instantiated.

```
var app = angular.module('newstalk',[]);
app.controller('articlectrl',[function(){
    console.log("hi");
}]);
```

The corresponding HTML for it is this:

```
<html ng-app='newstalk'>
    <!-- I have also included both angular js file and my js file in html-->
    <body ng-controller='articlectrl'></body>
</html>
```

The string hi is not getting logged.

Comment: Your code is working fine. Share your index while where you are including scripts.

Comment: you must have forget to add controller file & you are having error in console..could you check your console..

Comment: It works here: http://plnkr.co/edit/KA56emFPYMxBKnCJuT2G?p=preview assuming that you are indeed using Angular 1.x, not 2.x